# OutOfMemory on string which is response XML

Tags: java, android, string, out-of-memory

Conditions:

I have a URL, that returns me a XML, which is ~3MB of data.
I get this into a string, parse the XML, and save it. 
This complete process happens in an Async task.

Two problems:

1. My UI thread is blocked until the server data is parsed.
2. I get OutOfMemory error on String in most cases

// Calling code

```
{
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream in = entity.getContent();
value = convertStreamToString(in).toString();
return value;
}


// Helper function
    public static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
        try {
            return new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError ex) {
            CommonLib.ZLog("splash", "Out of memory exception while download");
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do your Network related work or downloading work into `Background` using `AsyncTask`. and if you have data size > 10MB then split it and `Running` into different `Thread`

Comment: I am already using Async task to perform tasks, I have also tried creating a separate thread, and in a service too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have that much of heap before the you get an OutOfMemoryError. Try using  [`getMemoryClass()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29) to figure out how much heap memory you have available.

You might try to [capture a heap-dump](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html#HeapDump) to check for memory leakage.

Answer (score 0):

Use SAX or PULL xml parser for the memory problem. How is your UI thread block when you are using ASYNC task blocking UI thread means you can't do anything on your UI thread until some operation is taking place. Whereas in ASYNC task that is not the case it just creates the new thread for the server response and updates the UI when response is retrieved in meantime who can do what ever you want in the UI thread. If you right some function after ASYNC task it will get executed surely on UI thread.

```
asynctask.execute();// runs on new thread
someotherfunction();// runs on UI thread meanwhile .
```